# How do I write a dockerfile to execute a simple bash script?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to write a docker image to run a simple webserver though netcat.

So I have in my docker build folder:

```
Dockerfile
index.html
run_netcat_webserver.sh
```

The `run_netcat_webserver.sh` is very simple and it works fine:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

while true ; do nc -l 8080  < index.html ; done
```

Here is my naive Dockerfile that of course is not working:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

CMD run_netcat_webserver.sh
```

How should I proceed to make this work inside a docker container?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make the script part of the container. To do that, you need to copy the script inside using the `COPY` command in the Docker file, e.g. like this

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
COPY run_netcat_webserver.sh /some/path/run_netcat_webserver.sh
CMD /some/path/run_netcat_webserver.sh
```

The `/some/path` is a path of your choice **inside** the container. Since you don't need to care much about users inside the container, it can be even just `/`.

Another option is to provide the script externally, via mounted volume. Example:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
VOLUME /scripts
CMD /scripts/run_netcat_webserver.sh
```

Then, when you run the container, you specify what directory will be mounted as `/scripts`. Let's suppose that your script is in `/tmp`, then you run the container as

```
docker run --volume=/tmp:/scripts (rest of the command options and arguments)
```

This would cause that your (host) directory `/tmp` would be mounted under the `/scripts` directory of the container.

Comment: How do I know what `/some/path` to use? I tried `/usr/local/bin` and it did not work :(

Comment: @TakeSoUp It's the path inside the container. It can easily be just ``/`` as you basically don't need to care about users inside the container. It's all isolated so why not...

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to just copy my script to the home directory (i.e. `~`)?

Comment: @TakeSoUp I don't know which home directory you mean (the one in container or the "normal" one, i.e. the host's) but you can certainly copy anything anywhere.

Comment: Great answer. You can use ENTRYPOINT too in place of CMD.

Answer (score 1):

Simple example

1. Write a "Dockerfile"

FROM ubuntu:14.04         - # image you are using for building the container

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/echo"]  - # command that will execute when container is booted

2. Verify that you are in the same directory as the "Dockerfile".
3. sudo docker build .

and you are done

sample output:

ahanjura@ubuntu:~$ vi Dockerfile

ahanjura@ubuntu:~$ sudo docker build .

Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.39 GB
Step 1 : FROM ubuntu:14.04
 ---> 67759a80360c
Step 2 : ENTRYPOINT /bin/echo
 ---> Running in c0e5f48f7d45
 ---> 7a96b36f528e
Removing intermediate container c0e5f48f7d45
Successfully built 7a96b36f528e