# How do I write a Dockerfile to run an interactive application?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, interactive

I'm fairly new to Docker, so please bear with me.

I need to understand how to write a Dockerfile that can run an interactive application, such as **mysql_secure_installation** (which allows the user to change root's password and indicate if the privilege tables should be flushed, for example).

PS: I know how to do the same when the application does not require interaction, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37471709/how-do-i-write-a-dockerfile-to-execute-a-simple-bash-script).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet will probably be to delegate control to an [expect(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) script from a RUN directive in your Dockerfile. For example:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM debian:latest
...
RUN mysql_secure_install.sh
...
```

**mysql_secure_install.sh**

Grab inspiration from the accepted answer on [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24270733/automate-mysql-secure-installation-with-echo-command-via-a-shell-script)

Comment: Thank you! I'll give this a try! Sounds like a real lifesaver.